# I can’t make icons be centered and at the correct size on my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navbar, center, navigationbar

I made a leftsided navigation bar that works very well, but I still can’t add any icons inside the buttons properly. [Here is the code of the navigation bar in CodePen](https://codepen.io/Eduardo-Trindade/pen/MWXMZvb/)
`codepen.io/Eduardo-Trindade/pen/MWXMZvb`

I tried adding the icons to the buttons, but it appears at the corner of it, not centered, and I couldn’t center it there.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason behind this is that you are inserting the icons inside the span element. Insert the icons inside the  tags and you are good to go.

The element span has the class toolkit making the icons appear at the corner. Try to have the icons, not inside the tooltip (span) class but instead inside the  element. Use the flex property to get the image in the centre of the buttons.

Comment: Thanks, but, which tag should I put it inside? I removed it now but still I can’t center it or choose the size, which is what I want

Comment: You have done everything fine now. Now just add some CSS property for the element that is inside of the nav. Maybe use the following:

nav a {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

Comment: then it would exactly work as you have wanted (per this post).